# POST 400 error in Firebase with React formik and yup?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, formik, yup

I'm currently working on the validation of the Login on my app and after testing it myself the console gives a 400 POST error

I don't think it's the intended answer since the password only has validation rules in min and max characters

Code of my LoginForm component:

(PS: how should i redirect should the login go right? I was thinking of redirecting to the homepage should it go okay, should it not it would just throw a warning if the user doesn't exist or an error if there was an error)

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity,Text } from "react-native";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import RegisterForm from "./RegisterForm";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import auth from "../../firebaseConfig";
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";
import Login from "../../firebaseConfig";

const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('El email ingresado no es valido.').required('Por favor ingrese su email.'),
    contraseña: Yup.string()
      .min(6, 'La contraseña es muy corta.')
      .max(20, 'La contraseña es demasiado larga.')
      .required('Por favor ingrese su contraseña.')
  });

export default function LoginForm () {
    return(
    <Formik initialValues={{
        email: '',
        contraseña: ''
    }}
    validationSchema={SignupSchema}
    onSubmit={values=> Login(values)}
    >
        {({values,errors,touched, handleChange, setFieldTouched, isValid, handleSubmit}) =>(
        <View>
            <TextInput 
            placeholder="Email" 
            value={values.email} 
            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
            onBlur={()=> setFieldTouched('email')}/>
            {touched.email && errors.email && (
                <Text>{errors.email}</Text>
            )}
            <TextInput 
            placeholder="Contraseña" 
            value={values.contraseña} 
            onChangeText={handleChange('contraseña')}
            onBlur={()=> setFieldTouched('contraseña')}
            secureTextEntry={true}/>      
            {touched.contraseña && errors.contraseña && (
                <Text>{errors.contraseña}</Text>
            )}
            <TouchableOpacity disabled={!isValid} style={{backgroundColor: isValid? '#289D8C': '#808080'}} onPress={handleSubmit}>
                <Text>Ingresar</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Link to="/RegisterForm" exact component={<RegisterForm/>} >¿No estás registrado?</Link> 
                </View>
                )}
    </Formik>
    )
}
```

firebaseConfig.js file:

```
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
//import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "--------------------------------",
  measurementId: "-------------"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

/* provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
 */
/* const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(); */

const auth = getAuth();

export { auth, db };

export default function Login({email, contraseña}) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, contraseña)
      .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in                 
          const user = userCredential.user;
          // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
      });
  
  }

/* auth.languageCode = 'it';

provider.setCustomParameters({
  'login_hint': 'user@example.com'
});

signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    const user = result.user;
  }).catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    const email = error.customData.email;
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
  });

  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
 */
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What is the issue you need help with? The POST request? The response? The 400 error? Something else?

Comment: I'd say the error, since i have no idea *why* it gives me a 400 error since it's apparently a bad request but i'm pretty sure there shouldn't be any issues with this

Comment: So there's an issue when calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword`? What is the complete error (code and message)?

Comment: "POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=mykey 400"